# adding value attribute on all src tags in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tags, src

can i adding some value attribute on all src tags in current html page with jquery ?
in example this html :

```
<img src="images/slider/slide4.jpg" />
```

to be like this :

```
<img src="http://www.website.com/images/slider/slide4.jpg" />
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var newSrc = 'http://www.website.com/' + $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

Edit: You don't need the `each` loop, ignore previous code (keeping it for reference); the `attr` function already does it for you!

```
$('img').attr('src', function() {
    return 'http://www.website.com/' + this.src;
});
```

See the last example in [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr#attr2).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is some shortest way.

```
$('img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', some_string + $(this).attr('src'));
});
```